# Python: Screenshot toggle switch (no Tkinter)

Tags: python, opencv, mss

I am looking for a way to use a hot key 's' to capture repeated screenshots. When the script originally runs, I do not want any screenshots being captured, but when I press 's' I want screenshots being recorded at a designated time interval. When I press 's' again I want the screenshots to stop being recorded.

Here is my current script, I have been able to make this work when taking in a video and using Tkinter but in terms of screenshotting the screen based on a toggle switch, I have only gotten it to work when the script screenshots already.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from mss import mss
from datetime import datetime
import time

def main():
    capturing = False
    
    # Create output directory
    output_dir = "output"
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
    capture_number = 0

    # Initialize screen capture
    with mss() as sct:
        monitor = sct.monitors[1]  # Adjust the monitor index as needed
        interval = 0.1  # Capture interval (10 times per second)

        try:
            print("Press 's' to start/stop capturing screenshots...")
            while True:
                start_time = time.time()
                frame = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
                
                if capturing:
                    name = os.path.join(output_dir, f"capture{capture_number}.png")
                    cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
                
                # Check for key press to toggle capturing
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
                    capturing = not capturing
                
                # Sleep to maintain capture rate
                sleep_time = interval - (time.time() - start_time)
                if sleep_time > 0:
                    time.sleep(sleep_time)
                capture_number +=1

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```